# flv does not play

Tags: flash, flv, jwplayer

I have a FLV file intended to be played with JW Players, however it won't play. I have windows server 2008, in IIS under the website I have .flv in MIME Types.

```
Extension: .flv
MIME Type: flv-application/octet-stream
```

But on the browser, FLV doesn't play, the player is displayed though so no problem with my flash player.

In my other server (windows server 2003), it plays.

Can someone help?

THanks

Answer (score 1):

What's `flv-application/octet-stream`? Looks wrong, the usual MIME type for FLV would be `video/x-flv`.

I don't know whether this would actually affect playback though. There are many possible faults; to investigate further if this doesn't fix it you'll need to look at the request and response on the network, either using a network sniffer or a browser HTTP monitor such as Fiddler (IE) or the one built into Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

A major issue I've run into with Flash Players is assuring that the FLV path is passed correctly to the player. "Does not play" is a pretty vague problem description, and the first thing to debug is whether the correct FLV is being requested. You can use a tool like [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6647) to observe the requests being made and if they are coming back missing.

Comment: I've tried to using an absolute path with no luck. So path problem is checked and it is not the problem as I tried on another server and works. What I meant by "does not work" is simply it won't stream, in other words you cannot see the movie playing. Thanks.